# Detectar cambio o recarga de pagina

Tags: javascript

Como puedo detectar un cambio o recarga de pagina para que pueda mostrar una alerta de confirmacion si desea o no salir de la pagina actual.

```
var res = confirm('It\'s time to change. Do you agree with me?');
  if (res) {
    event.target.nextElementSibling.textContent = 'Yes, let\'s go for it.';
  } else {
    event.target.nextElementSibling.textContent = 'No, this is not the time.';
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar la `API` de [Performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation) , *(aunque existen o pueden existir algunos problemas de compatiblidad)*  Igual puede ser una opción para detectar el `refresh` , cuando sucede este evento, el `type` es `1` , a partir de esto se puede realizar la validación

```js
  if (window.performance.navigation.type == 1) {
   if(confirm('Desea Actualizar ? ')){
     location.href ="https://w3c-test.org/navigation-timing/test_navigation_type_reload.html";
   }
else{
    alert('Correcto');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el evento `onbeforeunload`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return "You have some unsaved changes";
};
```

Por lo que leo, cada navegador puede poner distintos mensajes, posiblemente no sea posible crear un mensaje dinámico.

*Según esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup/38880926) los navegadores eliminaron la posibilidad de dejar mensajes dinamicos en distintas versiones*

Comment: intente con tu ejemplo pero nunca muestra el alert

Comment: @hubman actualice mi respuesta

Comment: ahora si funciona, otra duda mas como puedo hacerlo bonito el recuadro, quiero ponerlo estilos